# Python, how to write to a database while downloading the next datafile. Threading or multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have numerous datafiles to download and then add to the database.

Currently I am doing this sequentially like this:

```
for file in files:
   data = downloadfile
   writefile
```

This is clearly waisting a great deal of time as the computer can download while writing.
I have been looking into threading(helping with IO bound tasks) and multiprocessing(helping with CPU bound tasks)

My situation is IO bound, firstly it is Ethernet IO bound, then it is disk IO bound.  These 2 should be able to run simultaneously...

Should I be looking at threading or multiprocessing?

Basically I would like to do this:

```
dlThreadOrProcess = None
writeThreadOrProcess = None
nextWriteData = None
for file in files:
    if dlThreadOrProcess:
       while dlThreadOrProcess.isNotDone():
           pass
    dlThreadOrProcess = launchDlThreadOrProcess(file)

    if writeThreadOrProcess:
       while writeThreadOrProcess.isNotDone():
           pass
    writeThreadOrProcess = launchWriteThreadOrProcess(nextWriteData)
```

Basically the logic is, only 1 download thread/proccess can be running at a time and only one write process/thread can be running at a time but should be 1 of each running at the same time. Also of course the write portion needs data from the download portion.

Thanks

Comment: multithreading will do for that, and avoid surprises with data-sharing across processes.

Comment: as for me use whatevere you linke - threading, multiprocessing, joblib, ray, dask, etc.